# Shutdown program with right click or something

Tags: windows-8, skype, kill

I have Skype on my Windwos 8.1 computer and everytime I want to close the program I have to confirm twice that I really want to shut the program down. If I right-click on the Skype icon on the taskbar, I can choose to close the window, but this doesn't actually shut the program down/

Is there a smart way to force a program to shutdown? Are there any settings that can be tweaked or some small program that will let you kill a process without having to start the task manager?.

Edit: Doing Alt+F4 doesn't work. This just minimizes the window. (It seems that it does the same as "close window".)

Edit 2: I should have said this at the beginning. I am using Skype Portable version 6.18.

Comment: I think you're looking for Alt + F4

Comment: @CoproManiac: Alt+F4 doesn't work ...

Comment: Your using the Desktop or Windows Store version of Skype?  Because I was able to close the desktop version of Skype with that shortcut.

Comment: @Ramhound: Sorry, I am using a portable version.

Comment: If you use a non-portable edition does it work like it should?

Comment: @Ramhound: I have used a non-portable version where I didn't have this behaviour.

Comment: Your using an unofficial version of Skype.  There is a reason I am asking if you have used the desktop version.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, but my question still is: is there a smart way to close this program without having to confirm that I really want to quit. I am wondering if there is a small program that will in an easy way let you kill a program. Or maybe one could write a script or something like that.

Comment: You just right click on the icon in the taskbar and hit "Quit" but you claim that doesn't work.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, that doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because your not using an unofficial non-current version of Skype

Comment: @Ramhound: I understand. But my question could be independent of it being Skype. My question is: Is there a smart way to kill a process/program without having to go to the task manager?

Comment: Alt f4 will end most applocations but I still maintain if the application has a taskbar icon i.e left of the clock instead of the taskbar area

Comment: @Ramhound: Alt+F4 doesn't work.